# Share variables between hosts with Go

Tags: memory, go

I have an application write in golang,and it will load the basic data to global var,so make the application response fast,and export a http interface to update the var when user make changes to the database.

But i deploy another server,and used proxy.There comes a problem,when user send http request to the update url,it will load traffic to one of the servers.So that server update this var,but others not.

such as utils.go:

```
package utils

var BasicDatas map[string]*MyModel

func UpdateVar(){
// do some work
}
func PreLoadVar(){
// preload data to basicDatas
}
```

and the main.go

```
package main
import(
"codebase/utils"
)
func main(){
utils.PreLoadVar()
}
```

so if there anyway to share the var between multi hosts?Or any libiary can help do this work?

Nsq.io seem a good choice,but i want to seek  a more simple one if there is.
thanks:)

Comment: This is a classic Inter-Process Communication (IPC) problem and there's no one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your global variable is a very simple form of [caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache), which is well known to be problematic when you are running your application on multiple servers. There are several ways to fix this problem:

1. As suggested by Bill Nelson: use your database as the central storage and do not cache your data in your application at all.
2. Externalize your cache with a simple key-value store, for example using [Redis](http://redis.io/) together with one of the [many Redis clients in Go](http://godoc.org/?q=redis).
3. Use a distributed cache such as [groupcache](https://github.com/golang/groupcache).

If you have too much time on your hands you *could* use a messaging solution like nsq to implement your own distributed cache, but I would advise against it - this is not an easy problem.